# approach to migrate mongodb using mongomirror using 2 GCE only

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, database-migration, mongodb-replica-set, mongomirror

approach to migrate mongodb using `mongomirror`: Setting up mongodb instace on GCE and then migrate to another on GCE only

1. setting up 2 GCE on same project
2. Installed mongodb on both GCE
3. Installed mongomirror on source vm1
4. Tried exeuting mongomirror command on source GCE using username and pwd

```
./mongomirror --host rsMigration/SOURCE_IP --username root --password root123  --destination DESTINATION_IP:27017 --destinationUsername admin --destinationPassword admin123
```

Output:

```
mongomirror version: 0.12.2
git version: 9b30f320e44f90afec5c0fa792d4c003b71ead6b
Go version: go1.16.7
   os: linux
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
```

> 2021-10-27T07:57:03.252+0000    Error initializing mongomirror: could not initialize source connection: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: 27017:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 0.0.105.137:27017: i/o timeout }, ] }

Comment: did you resolved this issue?

Comment: Mongo mirror works with mongo atlas.